# check array exist in array using every and some

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have `arr = [1,2,3]` and `ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`. I want to find if any of the `arr item` exist in the `ids`. If yes the `invalid` is true.

Which of the below code is better? or they are the same thing?

```
const invalid = !arr.every((id) => ~ids.indexOf(id));

const invalid = arr.some((id) => ids.includes(id));
```

Comment: what is `~` in first statement?

Comment: @Nitheesh https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT

Comment: `const invalid = !arr.every((id) => ~ids.indexOf(id);` this is an invalid syntax. Missing `)`. If that is added, it will show false as output which is not the expected one.

Comment: @Nitheesh `~ids.indexOf(id)` is an obscure way of doing `ids.indexOf(id) >= 0`. Since `~(-1)` is `0` which is falsy. Whereas `~N` (where `N` is a non-negative integer aka natural number) produces some negative integer which is truthy.

Comment: @3limin4t0r  actually `~someNumber` is a way of checking if `someNumber != -1` and I personally find nothing obscure about it. Especially in the context of  `indexOf` because the "negative" (ie -1 = element is not found) result of `indexOf` is actually a truthy, whereas one "positive" result (ie 0 = element is found at index 0) is a falsey, and the `~` converts `-1` to a falsey and `0` to a truthy. But for only checking if an element is contained, I'd prefer `includes`

Comment: @derpirscher True, but in this context `indexOf()` only returns natural numbers and `-1`. So `ids.indexOf(id) >= 0` is the same as `ids.indexOf(id) != -1`. Our definitions of obscure probably varies, because I personally find `ids.indexOf(id) >= 0` or `ids.indexOf(id) != -1` a lot easier to read and understand than `~ids.indexOf(id)`. I do agree that `includes()` is the best choice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two statements have a very different semantics.

The callbacks are the same, ie `ids.includes(id) === true` is equivalent to `~ids.indexOf(id) != 0`. But `arr.some()` and `!arr.every()` have a different semantics:

- `some()` returns `true` if at least one element *fits* the condidition
- `!every()` returns `true` if at least one element *doesn't fit*  the condition

So actually your first snippet is not checking, if there is at least one element in `arr` that is *also contained* in `ids`, but if there is at least one element in `arr` that is *not contained* in `ids`

So the correct version of first snippet would be

```
const invalid = !arr.every((id) => !(~ids.indexOf(id)));
```

Ie, checkig if not every element of `arr` is *not contained* in `ids`. From a computational standpoint, they are more or less the same:

- `indexOf` and `includes` return on the first element element they find
- `some` stops when the callback returns `true` for the first time
- `every` stops when the callback returns `false` for the first time
- there is of course a (little) overhead for `~` and `!`

But if you compare this to your second snippet, it seems pretty obvious, that it is far more complex to read and understand and therefore far more complex to maintain.

```js
const 
  arr = [1,2,3],
  ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  
const 
  i1 = !arr.every((id) => ~ids.indexOf(id)),
  i2 = arr.some((id) => ids.includes(id)),
  i3 = !arr.every((id) => !(~ids.indexOf(id)));
  
  
console.log(i1, i2, i3)
```

Comment: so your conclusion is stop using `!` and `every`?

Comment: In that particular usecase, yes. because `arr.some(id => ids.includes(id))` also verbally expresses, what you are trying to do, ie check if "some" elements of `arr` are also "included" in `ids` ...